Movie where a cycle of killing pregnant wife continues and unborn baby lives
This movie was between year 2000-2005 
The storyline was supposed to be a mind boggler.  
The movie starts off with a man who and his girlfriend/wife move into a single-level suburban house; (they both were orphans and this comes to be crucial later in the movie). This man pieces the history of the house together and discovers that the previous people that lived there, killed his pregnant wife with an axe and then went outside, doused himself in gasoline and lit a match to catch himself on fire. When the ambulance arrive, they discover the baby is still alive inside the dead pregnant mother. 
The guy comes to the conclusion that he is the baby they cut out of the dead woman. Only to find out it wasn't him, it was his now pregnant girlfriend who was the baby. 
He starts to go crazy and kills her and himself in the same manner as the previous murder and the same thing happens- the baby lives. 
It was an american movie and in English, girl had brown hair. No names of characters but he was doing the rubrics cube throughout the movie and one day it showed it finished and he thought his girlfriend finished it but she told him he did.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
